# Assignment: Python 3.3: calling a class instance through an attribute

Tags: class, search, python-3.x, iterable

I'm running into some trouble with the "get_info" portion of my code. To be specific, my get_info works as long as I enter in the self portion and it corresponds to the instance in the class, i.e.

```
x=Person('Joe', 'Schmoe', '123-456-7890')
x.get_info()
```

However, I'm not sure how to bring up a contact's info by searching for the last name. As far as I know, classes are not iterable, so I cannot use a for loop. Clearly, there is something wrong with the bottom portion of my code, beginning with "elif x==2:" Here is the code that I have:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        self.first_name=first_name
        self.last_name=last_name
        self.phone_number=phone_number
        print("Initialized Person: ", self.first_name)
    def get_info(self):
        print(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.phone_number)

class Friend(Person):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, birth_date):
        Person.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number)
        self.email = email
        self.birth_date = birth_date
        print("Initialized Friend:", self.first_name)
    def get_info(self):
        print(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.phone_number, self.email, self.birth_date)

def main():
    exitprogram=False
    a=("1. Add Contact")
    b=("2. Lookup Contact")
    c=("3. Exit Program")
    while exitprogram==False:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
        x=(int(input("Please select a number: ")))
        if x==1:
            a1=("1. Add Regular Person")
            a2=("2. Add Friend")
            print(a1)
            print(a2)
            y=(int(input("Please select a number: ")))
            if y==1:
                f=(input("Please enter the first name: "))
                l=(input("Please enter the last name: "))
                p=(input("Please enter the phone number: "))
                new=Person(f, l, p)
            elif y==2:
                f=(input("Please enter the first name: "))
                l=(input("Please enter the last name: "))
                p=(input("Please enter the phone number: "))
                e=(input("Please enter the email address: "))
                b=(input("Please enter the birth date in m/d/year format: "))
                new=Friend(f, l, p, e, b)
        elif x==2:
            w=(input("Please enter the last name of the contact you wish to view: "))
            w=Person.get_info(w)
        elif x==3:
            exitprogram=True
main()
```

Comment: When you create a Person or Friend object, you assign it to a variable called `new`, but then what do you do with that variable? You're not storing it anywhere, so the next time you create a new Person or Friend object, the old one gets overwritten. Try making a list, and using `my_list.append()` to store your objects -- then you will be able to iterate over your list.

Comment: Like everyone is saying. Lists are probably best. If your interested in something that will do exactly what you are trying at 'elif x==2' there is something. You can look up metaclasses. With a bit of work a class inheriting from Person class can search among all the Persons. You would probably still need a list or a dictionary. They aren't the easiest thing or the best in all situations, but metaclasses can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store the contacts in a list. For example:

```
contacts = []
# To add a contact:
contacts.append(Person(...))
```

If you do this, of course, you can loop through it like any other list:

```
for person in contacts:
    if person.last_name == requested_last_name:
        person.get_info()
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. I realize now that it is so much easier to just add each contact to a list and then iterate through the list.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are iterable if you make them iterable, but that isn't going to help you here. You need to keep a list of people:

```
people = []
```

And when you make a new person, add them to the list:

```
person = Person(firstname, lastname, phone)
people.append(person)
```

Now, you can search through the list of people:

```
def search(people, lastname):
    for person in people:
        if person.lastname == lastname:
            return person

    return False
```